# Remove index.php from url by htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Im developing a php frame work and I am new to .htaccess rules. So I need to redirect 
url using .htaccess. Url is

```
http://localhost/rinocabs/index.php?/Galary/Image/
```

should be converted to this

```
http://localhost/rinocabs/Galary/Image/
```

in .htaccess file I include these rules

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
rewritecond %{http_host} ^localhost/rinocabs/index.php?/Galary/Image/ [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://localhost/rinocabs/Galary/Image/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

but its not working.  Please Help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s(.*)/index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
```

use this

> localhost/rinocabs/index.php/Galary/Image/

instead of

> localhost/rinocabs/index.php?/Galary/Image/

Comment: Usefull. Actualy it is good. but don't help for my problem. Thanks

Comment: have you tried with `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s(.*)/index\.php? [NC]`

Comment: I am interesting of your code. Im new to htaccess code. Could you please explain this code line by line. :)

I got the result like this with this url
localhost/rinocabs/index.php?/Galary/Image/ result is 

localhost/rinocabs/

Comment: this will convert index.php from the url. you are not using any virtual host. you should try a local domain. that will fix your problem.

Comment: no problem you can create domain in your localhost using virtual host as well

Answer (score 0):

[When in doubt, go the Codeigniter route!](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Basically there is no reason to include what's going to be the domain portion of your url in the rewrite rule and condition, and your condition is looking funky. Looking at the codeigniter example above, all we need to do in our expression is: find the index.php segment in the path, and get rid of it, and rewrite to include it. Your expression assumes the path will always be the same...if that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Ill go to check this.To try this code do I have to restart the server?

Comment: Indeedly do, it's gotta pick up your changes. Server restart is pretty darn simple though.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code. It's working properly.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

Comment: This would rewrite any URL to index.php OP whants it the other way around!

Comment: Thanks my friend. I have solved this problem. Thanks